# Can we use variable value provided in one if loop condition on other elseif condition

Tags: bash

```
if [ $TAG_VALUE = CORE ]
then
aws ec2 create-tags --resources $INSTANCE_ID --tags Key=Nodetype,Value=CORE --region $REGION
creip=$(ec2-metadata --local-ipv4 | cut -f2 -d " ")
elif [ $TAG_VALUE = MASTER ]
then
# For Tagging EMR Master instance

# Lets pass application.properties values as env variables

echo "Value of coreip is ${creip}"
echo "export coreip=${creip}" >> ~/dbenvmt
```

** I am trying to use value of creip derived from primary if condition in elif condition; but its showing empty value. How can I acheive this.**

Comment: No, because `creip` wasn't defined if `TAG_VALUE` wasn't equal to `CORE`, which is the only way your `elif` block runs. At first guess, it sounds like you want to set `creip` in *both* blocks, so that it is defined either way *after* the `if` statement is finished.

Comment: `creip=$(ec2-metadata ...); if [ "${TAG_VALUE}" = 'CORE' ] ... elif [ "${TAG_VALUE}" = 'MASTER' ] ...fi`

Comment: Cant we use value of a variable in another elif condition?